# how can I print all the files name and url from a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a code I have found and modify to create a list of files :

```
  var COLsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById("186TzknoKVEfMZOz-WpB-H1XX5HnpzAyx");
  var files=fldr.getFiles();
  var link=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';

    link.push([str]);
    
  }
  COLsheet.getRange(8,20, link.length, 1 ).setValues(link);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)

    var names=[],f,str;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    f=files.next();
    //str='=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '","' + f.getName() + '")';
    str='("' + f.getName() + '")';

    names.push([str]);
  }
  COLsheet.getRange(8,21, names.length, 1 ).setValues(names);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)



  Logger.log(link)
  Logger.log(names)
}
```

In this case it but don't work and tell  me :

*Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.*

if I turn off the line 23 like that :

```
  //COLsheet.getRange(8,21, names.length, 1 ).setValues(names);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)
```

it just return an empty list for   `Logger.log(names)`

I understand so far that when I whrote :

```
var link=[],f,str;
and
var names=[],f,str;
```

the troubles begin, I guess that the `=[]` call someting somewhere that I don't understand...

anyway to "declare" the 2 variable easely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- `files` of `var files = fldr.getFiles()` is `DriveApp.FileIterator`. In your script, `files` is used in 2 while loops. In this case, `DriveApp.FileIterator` is finished at 1st while loop. By this, `name` is always empty. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `files` is used in one while loop. And, the link and the name are retrieved in the loop.

```js
function sample1() {
  var COLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please set your folder ID.
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var ar = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var f = files.next();
    var str1 = '=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
    var str2 = '("' + f.getName() + '")';
    ar.push([str1, str2]);
  }
  COLsheet.getRange(8, 20, ar.length, 2).setValues(ar);

  console.log(ar); // You can see the value of "ar" in the log.
}
```

- When this script is run, the file list including the link and the filename is retrieved just under the folder of `fldr`. And, those values are put into the cell "T8:U".

#### Note:

- About `anyway to "declare" the 2 variable easely ?`, if you want to create 2 arrays of `link` and `names`, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
        COLsheet.getRange(8,20, link.length, 1 ).setValues(link);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)

          var names=[],f,str;
    ```
  - To

    ```
      COLsheet.getRange(8, 20, link.length, 1).setValues(link);//(range auquel on bake les valeurs)

      var files = fldr.getFiles(); // <--- Added
      var names = [], f, str;
    ```
- If you want to retrieve all files under the folder including the subfolders, I thought that the following modified script might be able to be also used.

  ```js
  function sample2() {
    var getFileNames = (folder, values = []) => {
      if (folder) {
        var files = folder.getFiles();
        while (files.hasNext()) {
          var f = files.next();
          var str1 = '=hyperlink("' + f.getUrl() + '")';
          var str2 = '("' + f.getName() + '")';
          values.push([str1, str2]);
        }
        var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
        while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
          getFileNames(subFolders.next(), values);
        }
      }
      return values;
    }

    var COLsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COLLECTEUR");
    var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please set your folder ID.
    var ar = getFileNames(fldr);
    COLsheet.getRange(8, 20, ar.length, 2).setValues(ar);

    console.log(ar); // You can see the value of "ar" in the log.
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getFiles() of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles)